# Attempting to prove a certain assignment of sieves on Top gives a Grothendieck topology

Tags: category-theory, topos-theory, grothendieck-topologies

Let $C$ be the category of topological spaces.

Given a topological space $X$, we say a collection $\{f_i : U_i \rightarrow X\}$ of morphisms in $C$ is a "covering family" of $X$ if each $f_i$ is a continuous open embedding (in particular also a homeomorphism onto its image),

and such that the images of the $f_i$'s cover $X$.

> (My apologies: I forgot to make the "covering families" actual coverings; I have now added the above line to include this requirement. Thank you to the comments who pointed this out.)

Let $\tau$ be the function on $\mathrm{Obj}(C)$ which takes each object $X$ of $C$
to the set of $C$-sieves $\xi$ on $X$ such that $\xi$ is generated by some covering family of $X$.

---

I would like to show $\tau$ satisfies the conditions for a Grothendieck topology (Definition 3.1 at the [nLab page](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/Grothendieck+topology#definition_using_sieves)).

- The maximal sieve on $X$ is always in $\tau(X)$, since e.g. it is generated by the open covering consisting of just $\{X \xrightarrow{ \mathrm{id} } X \}$.
- "Pullback stability" condition: let $f : Y \rightarrow X$ be a given continuous map, let $\xi \in \tau(X)$ a given $\tau$-sieve; then find a covering family $\{g_i : U_i \rightarrow X\}_{i\in I}$ which generates $\xi$; then, we can show the pullback sieve $f^* \xi$ on $Y$ is generated by the "pullback" covering family $\{ f^*g_i : f^{-1}U_i \rightarrow Y\}$ on $Y$.
- "Local character condition": let $\nu$ be a sieve on $X$, and let $\xi \in \tau(X)$ a $\tau$-sieve, and suppose for every $\left(Y\xrightarrow{g}X \right)\in \xi$
  that $g^*\nu \in \tau(Y)$. We want to show $\nu \in \tau(X)$.

  Since $\xi$ is a $\tau$-sieve, first find $\{f_i : U_i\rightarrow X\}_{i\in I}$ a covering family which generates $\xi$.
  The given condition implies that for every $i_0 \in I$, for a space $Y$ and a map $g : Y \rightarrow U_{i_0}$, then $g^*f_{i_0}^*\nu \in \tau(Y)$;
  i.e., there exists a covering $\{h_j : V_j \rightarrow Y\}_{j \in J}$ such that $g^*f_{i_0}^*\nu$ is generated by $\{h_j\}_{j\in J}$.

  In particular, for each $i_0 \in I$, take $Y = U_{i_0}$ and $g = \mathrm{id}_Y$;
  then the above implies there is a covering $\{h_j : V_j \rightarrow U_{i_0}\}_{j \in J}$
  such that $f_{i_0}^*\nu$ is generated by the $h$'s.

However, at this point I don't know how to proceed. My first guess is that the last line is saying that the $U_i$ for $i \neq i_0$ cover $U_{i_0}$, and we can take $J = I\setminus \{i_0\}$ and $V^{i_0}_j = U_j \cap U_{i_0}$; then somehow we can show that the collection
$\{  (f_i|_{V^i_j}   : 
 V^i_j \rightarrow X) \;|\; i,j \in J \,\&\, i\neq j\}$ gives an $X$-covering family that generates $\nu$, hence $\nu$ is a $\tau$-sieve. But unfortunately I'm not sure how to show these steps.

Would anyone have any suggestions on how to approach proving the "local character" condition? (Or, is my assumption that it should hold here incorrect?)

---

Edit: I guess the fact I am trying to prove for [coverages](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/coverage) on a general category $C$ is:

> If we take the sieves generated from a coverage as covering sieves, these sieves produce a Grothendieck topology.

Comment: So any family of injections is a  cover?

Comment: I’m assuming your definition is flawed, since you allow the empty set of arrows to be a cover.

Comment: @IndraneelTambe2 I think what everyone is trying to tell you is that you forgot to require that covering families be jointly surjective.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see, thank you, I had not noticed this error. I will update the question to fix it.

Comment: OK. It is not true that the "sieves containing a covering family" construction gives you a Grothendieck topology in general. For that you need a Grothendieck pretopology, which is a special kind of coverage. Fortunately, the open covering coverage is in fact a Grothendieck pretopology.

Comment: @ZhenLin I see, thank you very much! May I ask: would you know of a good reference which discusses the results you mentioned about the generated sieves of Grothendieck pretopologies giving a topology, and the open covering coverage being a Grothendieck pretopology?

Comment: I think the relationship between pretopologies and topologies is proved in MacLane–Moerdijk, among others. The open covering topology is in there too.

Comment: @ZhenLin Great, thank you very much for your help!